# React update existing css class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a library included in my project with React. That library has custom elements and custom CSS classes (I am not rendering the elements). However, I want to change the look of them in React. Basically, I want to dynamically change the CSS class properties used by the library.

```
i-bottom-right {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; => change that to right: 500px;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you add the library you use ?

Comment: [lib](https://github.com/Esri/react-sceneview)

Comment: You can add your own css with same class names and it would override the library css, as in most cases the library js and css comes on the top while our custom css comes in bottom, but there are exceptions. Just try modifying them and see.

Comment: The thing is that I want to do it dynamically. If the user clicks a button overwrite CSS otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to initialize the default class which is given library in State. like,

   constructor(props){
     super(props); 
     this.state = { classupdate:'libraryClass'}
   }
2. In your onClick event you have update your own class via setState,

   showHideClick = (event,rowIndex) => {
     this.setState({'classupdate': 'yourOwnClass'})
   }
3. Use the state in you respective Div or your element,
4. Add your own style in yourOwnClass

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem I found an ugly workaround, by creating an additional class (same as the library only one prop changed) and then using vanilla js `document.getElementById("useTheId").className = 'the new class name';`. Anyone with a cleaner solution would be happy to hear it.